# How to right model a MVC class diagram in UML?

Tags: oop, model-view-controller, uml

I am modeling a movie tickets system in UML. I need to use MVC so I must have a Model; which controls the available tickets in data base, a View; which asks the customer for some data and a Controller; which controls everything and is the path between Model and View. The thing is, I model this system like this:

[image: MVC Class diagram]

but my teacher said that I can't use a *Composition* relationship between the Controller and the View and Model. But I don't understand why because if I initialized the Model and the View inside the Controller (so it can control everything), when the Controller dies, both (Model and View) will not exist anymore. My teacher said I must use an *Association* relationship. Can you tell me what is the right relationship and why?

Answer (score 2):

The Controller in the MVC pattern manages the interaction between the Model and View, which are both independent things that **can exist on their own**, therefore it *references* them (association) they are *not* composite parts of it (composition).

I would also note in your UML class model example that the terms *Model*, *View* and *Contoller* are solution constructs in a *design pattern*, rather than specific types that you must have in your design or implementation. The "Model" in your scenario is probably in fact the *Ticket* business entity, and probably a bunch of other entities as well. The "View" is probably a "TicketDetailsView" or "ListTicketsView" and the "Controller" would be a "TicketController". In the original MVC pattern that was embedded in SmallTalk a View read the Model directly, and the Controller manipulated the Model, whereas there are now many variants of the MVC pattern in which the associations are not quite the same (MVP, MVVM, MVPC, Page Controller, and so on).

For reference I would highly recommend reading Fowler (https://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/uiArchs.html).

Answer (score 0):

The UML specs on p. 110 says:

> composite - Indicates that the Property is aggregated compositely, i.e., the composite object has responsibility for the existence and storage of the composed objects (see the definition of parts in 11.2.3).
>
> Composite aggregation is a strong form of aggregation that requires a part object be included in at most one composite object at a time. If a composite object is deleted, all of its part instances that are objects are deleted with it.

So that makes clear that the controller can not compose the `Model` because thats what permanently stores data. A composition would mean: if the controllers dies, the model shall die too.

About the shared aggregation you use (same box on p. 110):

> shared - Indicates that the Property has shared aggregation semantics. Precise semantics of shared aggregation varies by application area and modeler.

So you need to specify what you actually mean when using it. Or (even better) just leave that diamond away!